# Powershell script exits after pressing CANCEL button

Tags: function, powershell, exit

I have a powershell function that will prompt user for password twice, but as soon as CANCEL is pressed, the script exits. The script will prompt the user for as many matching pairs of passwords as possible, i.e. some users may have 5 passwords, others may have 10, etc to populate a text file and would like the stopping condition to be when the user presses `CANCEL`, i.e. when the user doesn't have anymore passwords to enter, `$continue` will be set to `$false`.

```
if ($confirmpassword -eq $null){$continue = $False; exit}
```

Here is the entire script

```
$working_dir = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$cred_path = "$working_dir\cred"
$pwd_path = "$working_dir\pwd"
$continue = $True



function createPwdFiles(){

    $stamp = $(get-date -f HH_mm_ss) 

    $password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString

    $confirmpassword = Read-Host "Confirm password" -AsSecureString

    $pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
    $pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($confirmpassword))
    if($pwd1_text -ne $pwd2_text) {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”) | Out-Null
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(“Passwords don't match, please try again”, “Passwords don't match”, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) | Out-Null

    } 
    else{
        $password | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $pwd_path\$stamp.txt
        Add-Content $cred_path\pwd_list.txt $pwd_path\$stamp.txt
    }
}

if (!(Test-Path -path $cred_path)){
    New-Item $cred_path -type directory | out-null
}

if (!(Test-Path -path $pwd_path)){
    New-Item $pwd_path -type directory | out-null
}


while ($continue -eq $True){
    createPwdFiles
}


write-output "hello world"
```

The line `write-output "hello world"` never gets executed.

How do I get CANCEL button to work so that `$continue` is set to `$False`, and the function is exited, but not the script.

EDIT

This is the Read-Host pop-up window

[image]

Comment: Which `Cancel` button?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The "Cancel" button on his `[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]` in the form of an X button in the top right corner.

Comment: I thought that `if ($confirmpassword -eq $null){$continue = $False; exit}` would address the issue because if the value of the textbox is null, doesn't this mean the `CANCEL` button was pressed? Hence I made value of `$continue=$False` so the function exits.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I included a screenshot of the Read-host pop-up window in my original question. If I press `CANCEL` the program exits without printing `"hello world"` to console

Comment: That only happens in ISE, in a regular PowerShell host it will prompt for input on the command line, not in a new window

Answer (score 2):

This is a Do{}While() kind of thing.

```
function createPwdFiles(){
Do{
    $stamp = $(get-date -f HH_mm_ss) 

    $password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString

    $confirmpassword = Read-Host "Confirm password" -AsSecureString

    $pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
    $pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($confirmpassword))
    if($pwd1_text -ne $pwd2_text) {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”) | Out-Null
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(“Passwords don't match, please try again”, “Passwords don't match”, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) | Out-Null

    } 
}While($pwd1_text -ne $pwd2_text)
        $password | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $pwd_path\$stamp.txt
        Add-Content $cred_path\pwd_list.txt $pwd_path\$stamp.txt

}
```

Comment: I added information to my original question, user can enter in as many password pairs as they wish...